# How to formulate this logic formula

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

The problem setting is very simple. Suppose we have three variables x, y and z and a constraints C/3 predicate that is satisfied by the three variables C(x,y,z), but C/3 
might not be the only constraint x, y and z meet, so the question is how do I formulate the set of all such constraints using logic formula.

Can I say

[image]

it feels awkward because the quantifier is supposed to restrict the variable instead of the predicate in a logic formula so the question is how should I approach this formulation, thanks.

Comment: I am confused. Is $C$ a boolean-valued function of its arguments?

Comment: @ncmathsadist, C is just a predicate to specify the constraint of x, y and z

Comment: @ncmathsadist, for example I can say x, y and z form an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, given three variables $x,y,z$ and a set of constrains $R$, you want to express the set $S$ of all constrains $C \in R$ (were $C$ must be some kind of equation) such that $(x,y,z)$ satisfy $C$, and we will denote this by $C(x,y,z)$. This set would be defined as (you were almost correct):

$S = \{C \in R | C(x,y,z) \}$. **This** is the expression you are looking for.

However, if you want the set $V$ of variables $x,y,z$ that satisfy the constrain $C$ but may also satisfy other constrains, this would be expressed as:

$V = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R} | C(x,y,z), C \in A\}$.

Where $A \subseteq R$ would be the set of constrains that $(x,y,z)$ satisfy.

I am a little confused, since $S$ is a set of constrains but $V$ is a set of points (e.g. variables), but you want a set of constrains and that the variables are restricted somehow. But, if you want a set of constrains, the variables play a little role, mainly only being used as the domain of the constrains. I hope this is useful.

Comment: Let's talk about one thing at a time, what do you mean by C(x,y,z) = 0 because C can be a very abstract term as long as it's some sort of a constraint so why does it equal to 0? thanks\

Comment: Sure you are right I do want a set of constraints where the variables are restricted, but we can consider the variable are fixed for example x = 2, y = 4 and z = 6 I can say one constraint is x, y and z form an arithmetic progression, I can also say z(6) = x(2) + (y)4, right so the question is how do I come up with a formula that covers all such kind of constraints.

Comment: A constrain is, generally speaking, "a condition of an optimization problem that the solution must satisfy." By this it means that it can be an equality or an inequality, since it must be a condition. More on this on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(mathematics)), but generally a constrain is an equation and this is why I put the equal sign, to denote that $C(x,y,z)$ is a function of the variables. This is motivated because of your use of the constrain $C$ as a function, but it's just notation.

Comment: Ok, just read your comment to the question. You may omit the equation notation and get to something very similar of what you originally posted.

Comment: Just want to confirm so it's Okay to put a quantifier to restrict the predicate as well as the variable then?

Comment: Yes, that is no problem as long as it's done the proper way. After all, logic is a language, and usually doesn't deal in absolutes concerning the properties of the universe, but rather on properties of certain restricted sets.